# How to Test In App Purchase Without Paying Real Money

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement In-App purchase in my Android Application. My Application's status of Play-Store is Unpublished. I using an authorized account for testing, But whenever i try to purchase a product in my Application using a Test Account, Play Store asks me for Credit Card details.
I have been researching on this problem , but haven't find an appropriate solution yet.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Screen Shots:
1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You don't have a CC, you must test with [Static Respond](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html). If you test with real money, you will be refunded. Don't worry about the test money, It will definitely be refunded (For me, it takes about 1 month).

Answer (score 4):

[The Hell of Testing Google Play in-ap Bililng](http://blog.suda.pl/2013/04/the-hell-of-testing-google-play-in-app-billing/) makes it look like payment info is needed.

> When you use a test account to purchase items, the test account is billed through Google Checkout and your Google Checkout Merchant account receives a payout for the purchase. Therefore, you may want to refund purchases that are made with test accounts, otherwise the purchases will show up as actual payouts to your merchant account

Seems an odd system but it may be the answer you were looking for.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have any CC info associated with my testing account. therefore i can't enter any CC info. Is there any way to purchase the test product without paying.

Comment: Not that I was able to find.  Even Google's documentation doesn't mention this directly, but I wasn't able to find anything more specific than this.